# Upload new App Update from a new Project

Tags: google-play

I have an App on the Play Store, already running.

Now I have a new update, but the fact is this code is from a new, different, project, so while the previous one was called 'scurcola' this one is something like 'scurcola_1.0-master'.

So even though inside the code I changed the package name in com.FET.leonardo.scurcola, it keeps saying I have to edit the package name in com.FET.leonardo.scurcola.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Had to edit the package name on the build.gradle (Module:app) too.

That fixed everything.